# MySQL Join with sum()

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables; One contains for products stats and another one contains additional stats

StatsHourly:

```
id
product_id (can be multiple)
amount
cost
time
```

StatsValues:

```
id
product_id (can be multiple)
value (double)
```

I need to join those two tables and get something like this in the result:

```
product_id
sum (amount)
sum (cost)
sum (value)
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
"SELECT
  SUM(s.amount) as amount,
  SUM(s.cost) as cost

FROM StatsHourly s
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    COALESCE(SUM(value), 0) as value
    FROM StatsValues
    GROUP BY product_id
) value v ON v.product_id = s.product_id
WHERE 1
  AND s.product_id = :product_id";
```

This doesn't work. Could someone show me the right way to do it?

Comment: Could you describe a little more what "doesn't work" means, precisely?

Comment: it just tells me that I have mySQL error and I can't see one; this query is a little too advance for me to be honest

Comment: SUM(s.cost) as cost, - The comma is wrong   SUM(s.cost) as cost  is correct. No comma after the last field

Comment: Usually, there is also a hint about the location of the error. (E.g. character position) Could you share this information?

Comment: sorry, I omitted a few lines after this comma, so this part should be fine

Comment: What if there are errors in the omitted lines?

Answer (score 1):

- You have an extra comma after `as cost`:

  `SUM(s.cost) as cost, <-- here`
- You also use 2 aliases for the subquery, you should remove value from there:

  `) value v`
- You do not use any output from the subquery.
- Coalesce() is unnecessary in the subquery.

Answer (score -1):

This works (tested):

```
SELECT
s.product_id as product_id,
s.amount_s as amount,
s.cost_s as cost,
v.value_v as value
FROM
(SELECT
    product_id,
    SUM(amount) as amount_s,
    SUM(cost) as cost_s
    FROM StatsHourly
    GROUP BY product_id) as s
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
    product_id,
    SUM(value) as value_v
    FROM StatsValues
    GROUP BY product_id) as v
ON v.product_id = s.product_id;
WHERE s.product_id = 'product_id';
```

The point is:

- As you have multiple equal product_id in BOTH table you have to make two aggregated tables through subqueries that makes the product_id unique and sum all appropriate rows.
- After that you can join and you select the already aggregated values.

Regards

Comment: If there are 2 records in each table with the same product id, then by joining them you will get 2x2 records in the output, and the group by function will operate on this inflated resultset. `Where 1 and ...` is a superflous, but legitimate condition.

Comment: @Shadow - Right: WHERE 1 is superflous, not an error. About the subquery you are also right, but you need to make a double subquery and then join. With only one subquery you get inflated values (the aggregated value rows are multiplied for the rows of first table). Then you use the values of aggregated tables for join. See my updated answer. Thanks

Comment: The 2 subqueries are superflous, you need only one as was written in the OP.

Comment: @Shadow, my sql works... Could you make me see how you would it with just one subquery. Thanks (What is OP?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106521/discussion-between-white-feather-and-shadow).